# MySQL: How to avoid ERROR 1055 (42000) when filtering by column neither grouped by nor aggregated

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns `id`, `value`, `category`. The primary key is `id`, `category`.

I want to do a query with result columns `id`, `category1`, `category2`, where the contents of the `category1` column correspond to the `value` column when `category = 'category1'`, and likewise for `category2`.

So:

| id | value | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 | category1 |
| 1 | 50 | category2 |
| 2 | 60 | category1 |

goes to:

| id | category1 | category2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 | 50 |
| 2 | 60 | null |

To start building this query I have:

`SELECT T.id as id, (SELECT MAX(T.value) WHERE T.category = "category1") as category1 FROM MyTable AS T GROUP BY T.id;`

I want to get this table:

| id | category1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 |
| 2 | 60 |

Instead I get an error:

`ERROR 1055 (42000) at line 12: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.T.category' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

What is going wrong? I would like to know how to fix it, but also conceptually why it is not allowed. I understand conceptually why every column in the output should be a GROUP BY column or an aggregate column. I prefer to avoid turning off the safety check (I mean `only_full_group_by`) and doing it the 'correct way' if there is such a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when category = 'category1' then value end) as category1,
       max(case when category = 'category2' then value end) as category2
from mytable
group by id;
```